# Indirect modification of overloaded property Fbevent::$location has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to push a string into an object. This error is thrown at the following line:

```
$event->location[0]->image = $mapLocation->image;
```

in this function:

```
public static function assignMarkers($events)
    {
        // Initialise pageIds array and counter
        $pageIds = [];
        $locations = [];
        $locationsCounter = 0;

        // Loop events and place unique pages in pageId array
        foreach($events as $event)
        {
            if ( ! in_array($event->location[0]->pageId, $pageIds))
            {
                array_push($pageIds, $event->location[0]->pageId);

                // Construct mapLocation object
                $mapLocation = new stdClass();
                $mapLocation->latitude = $event->location[0]->latitude;
                $mapLocation->longitude = $event->location[0]->longitude;
                $mapLocation->pageId = $event->location[0]->pageId;
                $mapLocation->image = 'assets/img/markers' . $locationsCounter . '.png';

                $locationsCounter++;
                array_push($locations, $mapLocation);

                // Push image back to event
                $event->location[0]->image = $mapLocation->image;

            } else {
                // it's already in the array
                // set the events image to the one in the corresponding location array position
                foreach($locations as $location)
                {
                    if ($event->location[0]->pageId == $location->pageId) {
                        // We have a match
                        $event->location->image = $location->image;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $events;
    }
```

$events is an Eloquent Collection (using Laravel). I'm not sure what the error means - can anyone help?

Comment: At a guess, because of the way your code is written, PHP thinks you are modifying a field on a relationship directly, and because there's not really a setter equivalent of the relationship getter, you get an error. You presumably could do it like this: `$loc = $event->locations[0]; $loc->image = $mapLocation->image;` However, that may fix the error but probably won't work, as you're then acting on throwaway objects.

Comment: Also I couldn't help but notice you refer to `$event->location` as an array at times (with [0]) and then towards the end (inside the if) you use it as if it's a normal object. Maybe there's something going on there.